# how to store multiple values of dynamically appended elements into a single var and retrieve then into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, settimeout

How can I store multiple values into a single variable and retrieve them into a setTimeout function.

```
  $(document).ready (function (){
  div ({'div':'#noo','auto':'true','pos':'top','txt':'hello'}); 
  div ({'div':'#bottom','auto':'true','pos':'bottom','txt':'hi'});
  setTimeout (function (){div ({'div':'#top','pos':'top','auto':'true','txt':'new'});}, 4000);
  });

  function div(obj) { 
     obj.div; obj.auto; obj.pos; obj.txt; obj.time; 
     var rec = {};
     if(obj.pos == 'top') { $('<ul id="top"></ul>').appendTo('body'); } 
     if(obj.pos == 'bottom') { $('<ul id="bottom"></ul>').appendTo('body'); 
    $(obj.div).append('<li data-name="' + $.now() + '">' + obj.txt + '</li>'); 
    if(!obj.time) { obj.time = 6000; }
    if(obj.auto == 'true') { 
        setTimeout(function () { 
                $(obj.div + ' li').fadeOut();
         }, obj.time);
     } 
  }
```

Now, how can I store "data-name" into "rec" variable and retrieve them into setTimeout function for hiding them when "obj.time" is over.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some mistakes in using jquery selectors. please use # to access by ID

```
 $("#"+obj.div).append('<li data-name="' + $.now() + '">' + obj.txt + '</li>');
```

also in setTimeout

```
  $("#"+obj.div + ' li').fadeOut();
```

I am confused in closing brace of second if condition. I closed in that line and its working fine. if you want to retrieve "data-name" to rec, you can use

```
 $("#"+obj.div + ' li').each(function(i)    {
    $(this).attr('data-name');
 });
```

for single or multiple values. also you can pass to setTimeout as a parameter.

http://arguments.callee.info/2008/11/10/passing-arguments-to-settimeout-and-setinterval/